# Algorithm to find combinations yielding a given total

Tags: combinations

I have several enormous spreadsheets of numbers. I want to search for combinations of cells which yield a certain value. Using a brute-force approach to try all possible combinations I am searching over hundreds of millions of combinations and the process is taking too long for my needs. This is searching over many, many combinations which aren't even close to reasonable (e.g. is 1+2+3 == 4,000 ?). Is there some way to limit the space of what combinations are searched over which is more computationally efficient? I can't just throw out "1" because 1 + 3,999 does indeed == 4,000

Comment: I think this is an instance of the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum)

Comment: Looks like you are correct, thanks for teaching me the term. I will continue to read that article now to see if there are clues for solutions.

Comment: Now I am going to try to put their one spelled-out example into code. My brain hurts.